# CSV to RDD to Cassandra store in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a bunch of data in a csv file which I need to store into Cassandra through spark.
I'm using the spark to cassandra connector for this. 
Normally to store into Cassandra , I create a Pojo and then serialize it to RDD and then store :

```
Employee emp = new Employee(1 , 'Mr', 'X');
JavaRDD<Employee>  empRdd = SparkContext.parallelize(emp);
```

Finally I write this to cassandra as :

```
CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(empRdd, Emp.class).saveToCassandra("dev", "emp");
```

This is fine , but my data is stored in a `csv` file. Every line represents a tuple in cassandra database.

I know I can read each line , split the columns , create object using the column values , add it to a list and then finally serialize the entire list. I was wondering if there is an easier more direct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just use the [SSTableLoader for BulkLoading](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading) and avoid spark altogether.
If you rely on spark then I think you're out of luck... Although I am not sure how much easier than reading line by line and splitting the lines is even possible...